# Unit Tests in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008, unit-testing, ssms

Is there a way to create simple unit tests for SQL queries in SSMS? I'm fairly new to T-SQL & SSMS, but I'd like to try to carry some of my old TDD habits into this arena, if possible.

So, for example, when I write the DDL to create complex functions and what-not, I'd like to have some way to include a unit test that (upon failure) would actually cause the output panel to display an error message upon execution. (This would be analagous to "breaking the build" in a normal programming environment.)

Currently, when I write a function that is syntactically correct, then hit F5 to execute it, the output message is:

```
Command(s) completed successfully.
```

What I am looking for is some simple SQL trick to simulate basic red-light/green-light test cases. So I would write a series of test-statements that would pass only if my user-defined function is operating as intended. Otherwise an error message would be displayed, such as:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid statement.
```

which would allow me to jump immediately to the failing test and see what I did wrong.

I don't expect there to be anything "built-in" for this, but is there some way I can "fake it"?

**Update:** I just learned you can [throw exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677615.aspx) in SS2012, which I'm sure I could use for just this purpose, but unfortunately I'm stuck with SS2008 for now. Is there anything comparable in SS2008?

Comment: Update: I just came across this useful writeup: ["Getting Started with Test Driven Design in SQL Server"](http://www.sqlmag.com/print/sql-server/test-driven-design-sql-server-142881)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are the 2 frameworks I can recomend

**T.S.T.**

http://tst.codeplex.com/

Testing SQL Server Code with TST

http://www.infoq.com/articles/tst-sql-server

**tSQLt**

http://tsqlt.org/

SQL Test (runner for tSQLt)

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-test/

**Update 1**

Reading your answer maybe you find the following *dump* useful.

TRY CATCH was introduced with SQL Server 2005 (and for this reason one should never look at someting older then 2005). You can actualy (re)throw an exception using a stored procedure mentioned in my dump, including the line number. In SQL Server 2012 they (finaly!) introduced throw as you mention makeing Tsql a robust language after 14 years.

So here is my dump, I need to clean it up some day so Its more copy paste friendly.

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF

DECLARE @message varchar ( max ) 
DECLARE @who varchar ( 255 ) 
set @who = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID) -- name of the currently executing sproc

BEGIN TRY

-- ======================================================================================
SET @message = 'HELLO'
EXEC Log @who, @message

         ....

-- ======================================================================================
SET @message = 'GOODBYE'
EXEC Log @who, @message

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH


        -- ======================================================================================
--If an error generated in a TRY block causes the state of the current transaction to be invalidated, the transaction is classified as an uncommittable transaction.
--An error that ordinarily ends a transaction outside a TRY block causes a transaction to enter an uncommittable state when the error occurs inside a TRY block.
-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx
       if XACT_STATE() = -1 rollback;

    -- ======================================================================================
SET @message = 'Rolling Back transaction if present'
EXEC Log @who, @message

     -- Its important to rollback the transaction at the very start of the catch.
-- Otherwise the records that are written to the log will also be roll backed.

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
BEGIN
ROLLBACK TRAN 
END

-- ======================================================================================
SET @message = 'Error Occured '
set @message = @message + ' ERROR_NUMBER() : ' + cast(ERROR_NUMBER() as varchar(max))
set @message = @message + ' ERROR_SEVERITY() : ' + cast(ERROR_SEVERITY() as varchar(max))
set @message = @message + ' ERROR_STATE() : ' + cast(ERROR_STATE() as varchar(max))
set @message = @message + ' ERROR_PROCEDURE() : ' +cast(ERROR_PROCEDURE() as varchar(max))
set @message = @message + ' ERROR_LINE() : ' + cast(ERROR_LINE() as varchar(max))
set @message = @message + ' ERROR_MESSAGE() : ' + cast(ERROR_MESSAGE() as varchar(max))

EXEC Log @who, @message

  exec usp_RethrowError


END CATCH


Error logging sproc and table

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Log]
(
@who varchar(255),
@message varchar(max)
)
AS

SET XACT_ABORT ON
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF

INSERT INTO [ApplicationLog]
(
[Date],
[Level],
[Logger],
[Host],
[Message]
)
VALUES
(
getDate(),
'INFO',
@who,
'dummy',
@message
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationLog] (
[Id]            [int] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Date]          [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Thread]        [varchar](255)  NULL,
[Level]         [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Logger]        [varchar](255)  NOT NULL,
[Host]          [varchar](50)  NOT NULL,
[Message]       [varchar](max)  NOT NULL,
[Exception]     [varchar](max) NULL
)


Rethrow an exception

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_RethrowError]
 -- BOL contains a good example of that, there is a stored procedure called usp_RethrowError

AS -- Return if there is no error information to retrieve.

SET XACT_ABORT ON
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF

IF ERROR_NUMBER() IS NULL 
  RETURN ;

DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000),
  @ErrorNumber INT,
  @ErrorSeverity INT,
  @ErrorState INT,
  @ErrorLine INT,
  @ErrorProcedure NVARCHAR(200) ;

    -- Assign variables to error-handling functions that 
    -- capture information for RAISERROR.
SELECT  @ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER(), @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE(), @ErrorLine = ERROR_LINE(),
        @ErrorProcedure = ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(), '-') ;

    -- Building the message string that will contain original
    -- error information.
SELECT  @ErrorMessage = N'Error %d, Level %d, State %d, Procedure %s, Line %d, ' +
        'Message: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE() ;

    -- Raise an error: msg_str parameter of RAISERROR will contain
    -- the original error information.
RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, 1, @ErrorNumber, -- parameter: original error number.
  @ErrorSeverity, -- parameter: original error severity.
  @ErrorState, -- parameter: original error state.
  @ErrorProcedure, -- parameter: original error procedure name.
  @ErrorLine-- parameter: original error line number.
        ) ;
```

Comment: When I first asked this question, I was just looking for some "one liners" that might accomplish my stated task, rather than full frameworks. But these suggestions are great -- I'll have to explore them. Thanks!

Comment: I'm a C# developer and I almost always do my logic in that language so I can unit test. But when working with 100 millions of rows transact sql can make the difference between an hour of processing or 12. It's good that these frameworks exist although I must day I relied on my own mini framework till now. I played with the above 2 though and they get the job done.

Comment: Thanks for the update, which led me to the original description of `usp_RethrowError` in [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179296(v=sql.105).aspx). Very interesting stuff! I'm not exactly sure how I might use it in my current situation, but I can see that it could be extremely useful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've found a possible solution to my own question: [RAISERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592%28v=sql.90%29.aspx). This "works" to some extent (at least in the way I was invisioning), allowing me to build basic tests like:

```
IF dbo.myTestedFunction(@parm) != @myExpectedResult
    RAISERROR('>> Unit Test FAILED! -- %d, 11, 0, @parm)
```

It's quirky, but it *does* display an error message which I can click on to jump to the offending line of code (which, in my case, is the failing Unit Test) -- albeit with some bogus info on the first line.

Comment: I updated my answer if you need (re)throw in sql >2005 and want to access the line number that originally caused the exception (C# jargon here)